# I need a file converter script

Tags: bash, loops

I need to convert a file that looks like this:

```
Fri Apr 14 15:42:02 UTC 2023

MemTotal: 65039504 kB 
MemFree: 41010436 kB 
MemAvailable: 45100588 kB

Fri Apr 14 16:35:01 UTC 2023

MemTotal: 65039504 kB 
MemFree: 40409508 kB 
MemAvailable: 44902852 kB

Fri Apr 14 16:36:01 UTC 2023

MemTotal: 65039504 kB 
MemFree: 40411232 kB 
MemAvailable: 44905376 kB
```

To something that looks like this:

```
15:42:02,65039504,41010436,45100588 
16:35:01,65039504,40409508,44902852 
16:36:01,65039504,40411232,44905376
```

Here's the script that I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

export TIME
export MEMTOTAL
export MEMFREE
export MEMAVAIL
export FILE="./SMALL-SAMPLE.txt"

while read -a LINE from $FILE
do
    WORD1=${LINE[0]}
    WORD2=${LINE[1]}
    WORD3=${LINE[2]}
    WORD4=${LINE[3]}
    WORD5=${LINE[4]}
    WORD6=${LINE[5]}
    WORD7=${LINE[6]}
    case $WORD1 in
        "Fri")
           TIME=$WORD4
           ;;
        "MemTotal")
           MEMTOTAL=$WORD2
           ;;
        "MemFree")
           MEMFREE=$WORD2
           ;;
        "MemAvailable")
          MEMAVAIL=$WORD2
          ;;
       *)continue;;
    esac
    LINEOUT="$TIME,$MEMTOTAL,$MEMFREE,$MEMAVAIL"
    echo $LINEOUT
done < $FILE
```

Here's the output:

```
15:42:02,,, 
16:35:01,,, 
16:36:01,,,
```

I've got a rookie mistake hidden in that script somewhere...any ideas about why I cannot get my data in?

Comment: Why not `while read WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 ...`?

Comment: You forgot all the `:`. `$WORD1` is `MemTotal:`, not `MemTotal`

Comment: So `"MemTotal")` should be `"MemTotal:")`

Comment: You should only print the output lines after you read the `MemAvailable` lines. Your printing it after reading each input line, so you'll mix up the variables from different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TMTOWTDI, a shorter Perl version:

```
<file perl -anE '
    push @a, $F[3]||$F[1]||();
    say join",",splice@a if @a>3;
'
```

- `-n` makes Perl run the script for each record/line.
- `-a` turns on autosplit of records (by whitespace) into array `@F`
- Append to `@a` the first defined of `$F[3]` (timestamp) or `$F[1]` (value). If neither is defined, appending `()` is a no-op.
- If `@a` has 4 elements, print them, and truncate the array.

---

Your code has a few errors and stylistic issues.

- As @barmar stated, you should only print a line of output when you see the MemAvailable line (and so you also don't need the `*`/`continue` clause)
- `read ... from $FILE` doesn't mean what you may think it does.
- You are not matching the trailing colon.
- You should normally quote variable use to avoid unintended word-splitting, globbing, etc (although that shouldn't happen here).
- You shouldn't use all-caps variable names - they are reserved for the system.
- There is no great advantage to defining new variables that only get used once.
- No need to export any variables.

```
file="./SMALL-SAMPLE.txt"

while read -a line
do
   case "${line[0]}" in
      Fri)
         time=${line[3]}
         ;;
      MemTotal:)
         memtotal=${line[1]}
         ;;
      MemFree:)
         memfree=${line[1]}
         ;;
      MemAvailable:)
         memavail=${line[1]}
         echo "$time,$memtotal,$memfree,$memavail"
         ;;
   esac
done < "$file"
```

Comment: even shorter perl: `perl -anE '$s = $F[3]||"$s,$F[1]" if @F; say $s if /Avail/'`

Comment: even shorter awk: `awk 'NF { s = NF>3 ? $4 : s","$2 } /Avail/ {print s}'`

Comment: I really like how you `perl` guys can make such small scripts. Also nice you managed to make OP's script work without heavy changes. I think the `Fri` condition is prone to errors though. It seems it stands for "Friday" so in other days it would probably not work.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be:

1. Remove all empty lines (with `sed '/^$/d' $FILE`)
2. Read four lines at once each iteration (repeating `read` for each one)
3. Extract the desired field using `cut` command

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE="./SMALL-SAMPLE.txt"

while read ltime; \
      read lmemt; \
      read lmemf; \
      read lmema;
do
    TIME=$(echo $ltime | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
    MEMT=$(echo $lmemt | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    MEMF=$(echo $lmemf | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    MEMA=$(echo $lmema | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

    echo "$TIME,$MEMT,$MEMF,$MEMA"

done < <(sed '/^$/d' $FILE)
```

Testing:

```
$ ./script.sh 
15:42:02,65039504,41010436,45100588
16:35:01,65039504,40409508,44902852
16:36:01,65039504,40411232,44905376
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne '
    if (/:[^ ]/) { print /\d+:\d+:\d+/g, "," }
    elsif (/: /) { print /(\d+)/, $. % 6 == 5 ? "\n" : "," }
    ' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
- if the line contains a colon followed by non-space, print the part that contains three groups of digits separated by colons, and a comma;
- otherwise, if the line contains a colon followed by a space, print the digits it contains, followed by a newline on every last line of a group, otherwise a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the trailing colons in your `case` choices (`"MemTotal:"` instead of `"MemTotal"`). But there are much simpler and much faster solutions (bash loops are slow).

Example with `awk` (tested with GNU `awk` and the `awk` that comes with macOS Ventura):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '/^Mem/ {print t,$2,$5,$8;next} {t=$4}' file
15:42:02,65039504,41010436,45100588
16:35:01,65039504,40409508,44902852
16:36:01,65039504,40411232,44905376
```

Explanations:

- `-v RS=` sets the record separator to empty lines.
- `-v OFS=,` sets the output field separator to commas.
- `/^Mem/ {print t,$2,$5,$8;next}` applies to records starting with `Mem`, prints the value of variable `t` and fields 2, 5 and 8 (the 3 sizes in the record), and goes to the next record.
- `{t=$4}` stores the fourth field (time) in variable `t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Fri Apr 14 15:42:02 UTC 2023

MemTotal: 65039504 kB
MemFree: 41010436 kB
MemAvailable: 45100588 kB

Fri Apr 14 16:35:01 UTC 2023

MemTotal: 65039504 kB
MemFree: 40409508 kB
MemAvailable: 44902852 kB

Fri Apr 14 16:36:01 UTC 2023

MemTotal: 65039504 kB
MemFree: 40411232 kB
MemAvailable: 44905376 kB' |
```

> ```
> nawk '(NF = NF)^(ORS = NR % 4 ? "," : "\n")' RS='\n+' \
>        OFS= FS='^(([^: ]+ )+|[^ :]+: )| [[:alpha:]]+.+$'
> ```

- more succinct ::

> ```
> gawk '(ORS=/v/?RS:",")^!(NF+=OFS=_)' FS='^([^:]+|[^ ]+) | [?-|].+$'
> ```

- extreme compression ::

> ```
> mawk 'NF&&/v/*($__=_=/: /?_","$2:$4)'
> ```

```
15:42:02,65039504,41010436,45100588
16:35:01,65039504,40409508,44902852
16:36:01,65039504,40411232,44905376
```